# CSS Select all Anchors inside LI, Inside UL without adding classes to each anchor

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the Next.

```
  <div data-role='navbar'>
    <ul class='mainNAV'>
        <li><a href='#home'>Principal</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Yo 360</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Mercado</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

So in CSS.. without adding a CLASS inside each LI or ANCHOR element.

How can i select all the Anchors inside the UL with the class 'mainNAV'?

So i can change font size, colors, etc, to all items..

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `ul.mainNAV a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul.mainNAV a
```

Would be the most basic selector. You could also use:

- `div > ul.mainNAV > li > a`
- `div > ul.mainNAV li a`
- `div > ul.mainNAV a`
- `div ul.mainNAV  li  a`

... and probably a couple dozen more ways

Comment: I guess you are right, i was using jquery mobile and it overrides, i had to use !important. Thanks

Comment: Ug, `!important` is almost never the way to go. Make sure your CSS rules are loaded last, and that they're [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the other rules you load.

Comment: Its probably an ugly way, but when you use Jquery Mobile or Bootstrap its just the easiest way, i think

Answer (score 3):

You can use an attribute selector to only target anchors:

```css
.mainNAV a[href^="#"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div data-role='navbar'>
    <ul class='mainNAV'>
        <li><a href='#home'>Principal</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Yo 360</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Mercado</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>Not anchor</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: will that select all anchors with links, or just the ones that have href='#'?  thanks in advance

Comment: @AlanDaniel realized that I misunderstood the question. This will only target `<a>` tags that are being used as internal anchors (with the leading `#`). If you want to target all links you can simply use `.mainNav a`

Comment: its still an interesting way and also helps me to learn more, thanks for your time Jesse